# @font-face with multiple font-size css declarations slow Firefox to a crawl

Tags: css, firefox, font-face, freeze, performance

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Gabriola;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: local("Gabriola Regular"), local("Gabriola"),
        url("Gabriola.eot"),                        /* IE 5+ */
        url('Gabriola.woff') format('woff'),        /* FF 3.6, Chrome 5, IE9 */
        url('Gabriola.ttf') format('truetype'),     /* Opera, Safari */
        url('Gabriola.svg#Gabriola') format('svg'); /* iOS */
}
body {
    font-family: Gabriola, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.wine_name { font-size:2em; }
.price { font-size:2.6em; color:#CCC; }
.sugar { font-size:2em; color:#980000; }
br { page-break-after: always; }
```

The page displays quickly because I have Gabriola already installed.  When I remove the local() references, the file downloads...but Firefox freezes for around 20 seconds before finally rendering the page.  This is because of the multiple font-size declarations.  When I remove them, it renders fast whether or not I specify local() sources.  Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I've even tried lazy-loading of the fonts in case it had something to do with the CSS being inline for some reason.  Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm impatient but I seem to be answering my own questions a lot lately :S

Turns out there's either A) something wrong with the font file itself and/or B) Firefox isn't good at parsing certain types of fonts...

I downloaded a different script font (akaDora) and tested it...it works just fine.  No lag. No delay.  Now of course I'm tasked with finding font-face files for Gabriola that don't make Firefox barf.  Anyone know of them?  I got both fonts tested from http://www.fonts2u.com/.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out and posted the answer (don't forget to accept it) but the enclosed follow-up question risks veering this off-topic.  Perhaps [one of these free services](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/7-free-tools-to-identify-a-font/) will help identify a similar font.